# Get Dependency List from Depend

Tags: ndepend

I'm using NDepend to help manage a project and I was just asked to get an ordered list of dependencies (for build ordering of different solutions) based on what was using, both directly and indirectly, a given assembly.

NDepend provides a fine way of finding those modules that are dependent on that assembly, but no way of ordering it in the way I want.  For instance I can run

```
from a in Assemblies 
let depth0 = a.DepthOfIsUsing("Assembly1".MatchAssembly())
where depth0  >= 0 orderby depth0
select new { a, depth0 }
```

and that will get me a list like this

```
Assembly1 0
Assembly2 1
Assembly3 1
Assembly4 2
```

Which essentially means that Assembly2 and Assembly3 have direct dependencies on Assembly1, and Assembly4 has a dependency on either Assembly2 or Assembly3.

My problem exists because Assembly3 has a dependency on Assembly1 **AND** Assembly2.  And if Assembly4 only had a dependency on Assembly 2, I'd like to see a list like this:

```
Assembly1 0
Assembly2 1
Assembly3 2
Assembly4 2
```

If Assembly4 also had a dependency on Assembly3, then the list should look like this:

```
Assembly1 0
Assembly2 1
Assembly3 2
Assembly4 3
```

Now I can export the original list to a dependency graph, and view it horizontally, and manually fill out that dependency list myself, but I've actually got 123 assemblies in my hierarchy and that's a hell of a job, especially when I have other processing to do after that (something I know can't be achieved with NDepend), so I'd rather find a way of do this in CQL.

Anyone with ninja NDepend skills know how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly with a bit of astute it is possible, but my question is: why you'd be interested by the 'longest path' instead of the 'shortest' path that is provided by NDepend?

Comment: Hi Patrick.  We need to figure out a build order for a set of components we've "inherited".  So without knowing the full path, it's a trial and error effort to figure out what to build in what order.  I was hoping NDepend would be able to help me out here, but my ndepend-fu isn't up to it.

Comment: Did you notice the Assemblies Build Order section in NDepend report? http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports/OnNUnitNew/NDependReport.html#AssembliesBuildOrder

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam -> Sorry I've been away.  No I had not noticed that.  I'll have a quick look and let you know how I get on.  Thanks.

Comment: OK.  All I get is this: 

Some dependency cycles exist between .NET assemblies of your application.
Dependency cycles between .NET assemblies is a major code smell and it is recommended to refactor the code to avoid cycles.
Also, dependency cycles between .NET assemblies prevent from finding a build order between .NET assemblies.

Unfortunately it doesn't help me identify which assemblies have the dependency cycle :'(  

Is there any way of generating this in CQL?  the whole list, not just the dependency cycles???

Comment: Indeed "dependency cycles exist between .NET assemblies" is without a doubt a code smell that must be fixed. To get info to get rid of this small, you need to use the dynamic Dependency Structure Matrix (not the static PNG one in the report). http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx   Two papers are available about how to use the matrix to get rid of cycles. Focus on the second papers, what is written for hunting namespaces cycles with matrix is applicable to assemblies cycles as well: http://www.ndepend.com/WhiteBooks.aspx